# sql server data length

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have String data. what is type of columns in sql server 2014 when length More than 150000 character

Comment: Maybe `LONGTEXT`

Comment: `VARCHAR(MAX)` can handle up to 2 billion characters (in theory), which would seem to cover your requirement.